# Microsoft Graph API call for calendar events gives status 400 on ADFS identity tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

When I try to access the API `'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/' + users[i].id + '/events'` using node.js, the response returned has a status 400. I tested this code on the cloud identity trial tenant for our organization and it worked fine, whereas I get an error while running it on the ADFS identity tenant for our organization.
The code uses client credentials flow without user interaction to access data for all users. The steps I have followed are

1. Register application on Azure AD
2. Obtain application ID and OAuth2.0 token end point from Azure AD
3. Set application permission for Microsoft Graph API(Read directory data, Read Calendars in all mail boxes)
4. Obtain client secret
5. To obtain bearer token, the code makes a post request to the OAuth2.0 token end point providing Application ID and client secret in request parameters
6. Using the bearer token in request header, a call is made to `'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,displayName'` to get the list of all users in the organization
7. The API `'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/' + users[i].id + '/events'` is called individually for all users in the organization

Steps 5 and 6 work fine on both tenants but 7 throws an error on ADFS tenant with status 404. Is any additional permission required for tenants which use ADFS identity?

Comment: Is this an on-prem Exchange Server or Exchange Online?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT It is exchange online

Comment: Are you able to authenticate as a user in that directory and get `/events` from a that mailbox? I understand you're using client creds but this might give you a clearer error message than just a `404`.

Comment: I can try it out. Do you know why this could happen?

Comment: Have you assigned the correct licence to the user sync from local Active Directory? You can check whether the account can [Office 365-Outlook](https://outlook.office365.com) successfully.

Comment: @FeiXue I am relatively new to this. Could you please elaborate a little?

Comment: Does the user you tested own the online mail on Office 365 since the Microsoft Graph event method is used for that?

Comment: @FeiXue By user you tested, do you mean the user I tried to pull the data for? If yes, I am not sure about this. I know that no mails are stored on-premise, they're stored on exchange online

Comment: I think @FeiXue and I were leaning towards the same theory, that the reason `/users` works and `/events` fails is that these users don't have a mailbox (thus `/events` returns `404 Not Found`). The exorcise we were suggesting is effectively the same, although his is far easier to execute: Test if a user that is failing login and see their email/calendar by going to https://outlook.office.com/owa/.That will help rule out a missing mailbox as the issue.

Comment: Thanks @FeiXue and @MarcLaFleur. That was the issue. Do you know why Microsoft Graph API handles certain errors by giving an error message in the response body and does not handle some. In our case the former had an error message - `Resource {resource} does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present`  in response.body and the latter had an empty string.

Comment: @VipinChacko I think this is a specific issue for Microsoft Graph REST. And if you any idea or feedback about it, you can rise it from [this site](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I and MarcLaFleur suspect, the root cause for this issue is that the user does't own the mailbox for Office 365.

I also made a test the the Azure AD account which doesn't have mailbox with correct access token, the error is **UnknownError** with `401` response. If anyone who have this issue, you may check whether the account own the mailbox first.

[image]